# How to refer directly to an R object whose name is given as a string object?

Tags: r

I want to read csv files and then append the column names in each object based on the filename as follows:

```
for (fname in c("abc", "def", "ghi")) {
    assign(fname, read.csv(paste(HOMEDIR, fname, pnl.csv, sep="/")))
    names(?) = paste(names(?), fname, sep="."))
}
```

I am facing issues in the renaming part. What should replace `?`?

I have tried `get(fname)`, `as.name(fname)`, `as.symbol(fname)`, etc.

Comment: hi, you should consider importing your files in a list, it would make it much easier to work with them afterwards, moreover if you want to apply the same codes to each

Comment: I feel like a broken record. Forget that `assign` exists. Your approach only leads to further pain ahead. Learn to use a list for a collection of objects, especially if you want to loop over them.

Comment: Relevant post, keep your files in a list object: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-at-once

Comment: I don't understand why my answer is deleted? @zx8754 can you please explain why?

Comment: @SaiPrabhanjanReddy All the answers should be deleted... question is wrong. The right solution to actual problem is in linked post, as simple as `myfiles <- lapply(list.files(pattern="*.csv"), read.delim)`

Comment: Then how come one answer exist till on the list? And if the question is wrong, that is our duty to say the posted person to write it with an example or with more clarity, etc.. but not delete the answers. Correct me if i am wrong. Thanks

Comment: @zx8754 thanks for your unkind words. Few clarifications:

1) I believe the question is quite correct and unambiguous, since I got an accepted solution by Roland.
2) What you're telling is definitely **NOT** the right solution because you are answering a different question altogether - I do not have the urge to read all csv files, and they are NOT located in a single directory.

Comment: Roland provided the answer, yes it works. Of course it is your choice. Using the linked post we can get a better solution: `myData <- lapply(c("abc", "def", "ghi"), function(i)read.csv(paste(HOMEDIR, i, "pnl.csv", sep = "/")))`. No need for `get/assign/forloop/as.name/as.symbol`.

Comment: @SaiPrabhanjanReddy I realize that you couldn't test your answer because there is no minimal reproducible example provided, but your answer was simply wrong. I wouldn't have deleted it, a downvote is the appropriate action in such a case. Kaushal, personally I would use `lapply` but a `for` loop is OK too and easier for beginners.

Comment: Please do not see my comments as personal, see it as info only. No offence intended. Apologies.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs @zx8754. This is quite elegant and helpful. I was trying to use lapply as you mentioned earlier, but as a beginner faced issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list. You cannot combine `get` with `names<-` assignment because `get` returns a temporary copy of the object. And obviously you don't need to. Your approach is bad practice. Use a list.

```
mylist <- list()

for (fname in c("abc", "def", "ghi")) {
    mylist[[fname]] <- read.csv(paste(HOMEDIR, fname, pnl.csv, sep="/"))
    names(mylist[[fname]]) <- paste(names(mylist[[fname]]), fname, sep="."))
}
```